# Sending cURL data to multiple URLs

Tags: bash, curl

My code consists of the following:

```
curl -k -X DELETE \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: staticid" \
-H "X-Parse-Master-Key: statickey" \
https://mystatic.url/dynamicvalue
```

I have a list of URLS:

https://mystatic.url/johndylan

https://mystatic.url/marypoppins

etc, included in a tobedeleted.txt file and I would like to modify my cURL code to be something like this (which I've tried but didnt work:

```
curl -k -X DELETE \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: staticid" \
-H "X-Parse-Master-Key: statickey" \
> tobedeleted.txt
```

or to something like this (which also I've tried but it didnt worked)

```
curl -k -X DELETE \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: staticid" \
-H "X-Parse-Master-Key: statickey" \
https://mystatic.url/$tobedeleted.txt
```

Note that i want to run the same cURL command, each time for each line of the file, so I guess that I would need something like foreach function, since this is a bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want something like this:

```
while read value
do

    curl -k -X DELETE \
    -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: staticid" \
    -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: statickey" \
    https://mystatic.url/$value

done < tobedeleted.txt
```

Comment: Or append all the URLs in a single command line to make it run faster, since then curl will do the same request to them all and reuse connection etc.

Comment: It works fine for a few values, however, I have a list of 12.000 values and I get this message returned: curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL - Any ideas?